# javascript electron function shell.openExternal(url) take time to open link

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I have a problem with a javascipt function used on electron.

```
const {shell} = require('electron');
function link() {
shell.openExternal(url)
}
```

When i click on my call button i need to wait 2 min to see my link open on the default macOS browser.

When the page is open from the first click two min ago, when I click again on button it's now intant to open the link I can open it 10 times in 10 sec.

Why I need to wait 2 real minutes for the first apparition of the link on my chrome browser. Note that I'm actually on macOS